# React Fragment Not Rendering in Jest Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm testing some components and having trouble rendering the rows of a **material-ui table** **specifically when testing with React Testing Library**. I'm using react fragments to loop through an array and create the table rows of a material-ui table. I've included the code in the following code sandbox. It works as expected  in this case. However, when running the tests,  renders properly, but  does not render it's contents.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsibletable-material-demo-forked-mowdw?file=/demo.js)

My testing code is as follows:

```
// Link.react.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, fireEvent, render, waitFor, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import {InvoiceRow, InvoiceBreakdown} from '../components/billing/InvoicesBreakdown';
import SongUtils from '../components/songs/api.songs';
jest.mock('../components/songs/api.songs');

// ...

describe("SongBreakdown", function() {

  test('SongBreakdown renders appropriately', async () => {
    var {container} = await render(< SongBreakdown />);
    screen.debug();
    const tablerow = await container.querySelectorAll(".SongRow-root-1");
    expect(tablerow.length).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

"screen.debug" Shows the resulting html after rendering. It lacks any of the react.fragments that should be printed.

Comment: 1. React fragments are not rendered in the DOM by design. 2. I don't see that `SongRow-root-1` class anywhere, did you mean to use `SongRowBase-root-1`?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. As for your second comment, I used withstyles on songrowbase and saved it as songrow.

Comment: Couple of questions, as @tromgy stated fragments itself won't render, but the children should. To make sure, I want to ask if children of the fragments are rendering? Along with that is there a specific reason you are querying based off class? As an aria-label might provide to be more reliable.

Comment: Is your real SongBreakdown component fetching the data from the API file you're mocking? It might be a mock data issue

Comment: What are the react.fragments that should be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
var {container} = await render(< SongBreakdown />);
    screen.debug();
```

To

```
var {container, debug} = await render(< SongBreakdown />);
    debug();
```